# Local CSS file dropping off from plotly dash app

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I am running a Plotly Dash app and I append my local CSS file with:

```
app = dash.Dash(name, assets_folder='path_to_css.css')
```

All works as expected. I modify my CSS, my layout changes etc.

After a short while, say 10 minutes, the app looses connection to the CSS file and formatting reverts to default.

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`assets_folder` should be the path to the folder that contains your CSS files, not a CSS file path. Unless you need to call your folder something else, the simplest thing to do is create a folder called `assets` (which is the default value) and place your CSS files in there.